# state is not updating after onclick event occurs - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I have to show two modal one after another. When I click yes button of first modal then second modal will open. So, I set a boolean value on first modal handle click if it is true then second modal will populate.

```js
handleShowFirstModal() {
  this.saveJobsData();
  store.getOtherData(null);
  this.handleShow2ndModal();
  this.setState({ isOpenModal: false, WarningModalContentProps: {} });
}

handleShow2ndModal(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.setState(prevState => ({ isShowModal: !prevState.isShowModal }));
}
```

initial state of isShowModal is false. So, when first handle click occurred then isShowModal will be true. In modal I have setState with current state value of isShowModal. But, all over the component it is taking the value 'false'. What is the problem? Why it is not updating the state. Two modal is working fine independently. But, I need to open one modal after click event happens of first modal.

How can I do that using this isShowModal state. Modal code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
handleShow2ndModal =(e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();
 this.setState(prevState =>({isShowModal:!prevState.isShowModal}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using modern javascript ()=> function

```
handleShow2ndModal =(e)=>{
 e.stopPropagation();
 this.setState(prevState =>({isShowModal:!prevState.isShowModal}));
}
```

Because probably `this` is refering to event listener.

If you will use arrow function
Then `this` will always refer to class properties

Answer (score 0):

In `handleShowFirstModal` method you are calling the method `this.handleShow2ndModal();`. So the state `isOpenModal` initial value will be `true`.

Then the very next line(`this.setState({isOpenModal : false, WarningModalContentProps:{}})`) you are updating the state as `false`. That is the reason you are always getting 'false' value all over the component.

Possible solution:

```
handleShowFirstModal() {
  this.saveJobsData();
  store.getOtherData(null);
  // this.handleShow2ndModal();
  this.setState({ isOpenModal: false, WarningModalContentProps: {} });
}

handleShow2ndModal(e) { // Call this method when you are close the first popup model.
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.setState(prevState => ({ isShowModal: !prevState.isShowModal }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can bind your function in the class constructor like

```
this.handleShowFirstModal = this.handleShowFirstModal.bind(this);
```